# Trouble in writing equation

Tags: equations, symbols

I am having trouble while writing two things.

1. [image] I am confused how to write upper and lower limits to this.
2. [image: List item] and how to write this in latex

anyone can help me with this?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436)! Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. In other words what have you tried so far?

Comment: I'm also going to chime in with: what are you using to learn LaTeX?  Subscripts with `_` and superscripts with `^` are one of the first things that a LaTeX guide should let you know about.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following example shows how to write both expressions.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\( \lVert \mathbf{W} \rVert_F^2 \)

\( \min\limits_\theta \)
\end{document}
```

[image]

To answer more precisely your questions, the `\rVert` command writes the "||" character at the right of the "W", and the `_` after the `\rVert` is used to write the following entry (`F` in this case) in subscript whereas the `^` after it is used to write the following entry (`2` in this case) in superscript.

Also, I think I should mention that the `\limits` command after the `\min` command is not mandatory in general. It is used here because the equation is written in an inline-math environment (delimited with `\(...\)`). In such an environment, the equation is in `\textstyle` format, so by default the `\theta` called with `\min_\theta` would be typeset on the lower right corner of the "min" text, like this:

[image]

The `\limits` command asks to typeset the upper and lower limits on the top and on the bottom of the symbol, respectively. This behavior is often (for most symbols with limits, I think) the default in `\displaystyle`, which is the default format in a block-math environment (like those delimited with `\[...\]`). In a block-math environment, typing simply `\min_\theta` would give the same output as on the first image, even without the `\limits` command.